# Flutter repaint and rasterize entire screen on changing TextField cursor

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, repaint, rasterize

I have a very simple flutter app which render a TextField in the middle of screen.
Here's widget tree: MaterialApp > Scaffold > Center > Padding> RepaintBoundary > TextField
[image]

[image]

Here is the screen when the app just started, everything ok, repaint border show on everything on the first render
[image]

But when I tap on the TextField, the keyboard open, entire screen is repainted and 1 strange thing happen:
The entire screen is covered by raster-cache checkerboard?
[image]

From there, every time I change the cursor position or change the text in TextField, the raster-cache checkerboard which cover the entire screen update to a different color.
The TextField gets repainted ( which is normal) but the entire screen also gets repainted too which is strange because I already wrap the TextField in RepaintBoundary?
You can see the repaint border on TextField and the entire screen has been updated to new color.

[image]

Here's what happen on the timeline every time I updated the textfield:
[image]

My question is: why did the entire get raster-cached and repainted when I focus the TextField or update the cursor position?